# How do I insert more space between a post type and its tags (on tumblr)?

Tags: html, css, themes, blogs, tumblr

So I recently figured out how to add tags to a theme, but now I'm having trouble with the spacing. Everything looks perfectly fine on text posts and picture posts [(example)](http://oliveblair.tumblr.com/post/69732756591/i-did-it-i-finally-did-it) but for some reason, everything's all compressed on quotes and [(chat posts)](http://oliveblair.tumblr.com/post/69750866359/me-wow-i-have-so-much-work-to-do-me-goes-on).

The code for chat posts is as follows:

```
        <div class="conversation post">


                    {block:Title}
                        <h2>{Title}</h2>
                    {/block:Title}

                    <ul>
                        {block:Lines}
                            <li class="member{UserNumber}">
                                {block:Label}
                                    <span class="label">{Label}</span>
                                {/block:Label}
                                {Line}
                            </li>
                        {/block:Lines}
                    </ul>

    {block:HasTags}
    <p class="tagged">{lang:Tagged}: {block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}</p>
    {/block:HasTags}


                    <div class="postmeta">{block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a>&nbsp; {/block:Date}
    <a href="{Permalink}" style="text-transform:lowercase;">{lang:Notes} ({NoteCount})</a></div>

                </div>

                {block:PostNotes}
                    <div>{PostNotes}</div>
                {/block:PostNotes}

            {/block:Chat}
```

Any advice for code I can add or alter to get the space I want between the post itself and the tags???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I read that wrong...

Where you have

```
<ul>
    {block:Lines}
        <li class="member{UserNumber}">
           {block:Label}
            <span class="label">{Label}</span>
            {/block:Label}
            {Line}
         </li>
      {/block:Lines}
</ul>
```

Change it to

```
<ul style="margin-bottom:50px">
    {block:Lines}
        <li class="member{UserNumber}">
           {block:Label}
            <span class="label">{Label}</span>
            {/block:Label}
            {Line}
         </li>
      {/block:Lines}
</ul>
```

The 50px (50 pixels) is the gap